# tensorflow object detection export_inference_graph.py ckpt name

Tags: tensorflow, export, object-detection

Does `export_inference_graph.py` need an exact checkpoint number, or is there a way to run it so that it will use the highest numbered checkpoint in a directory?

Answer (score 0):

It needs exact checkpoint number in the command to find the correct file.